# Is there an easier way to multiple if else JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I am new to JS and wrote this up. Basically I stacked the images with absolute position and 0 opacity and when you click a button it brings that picture to opacity to 1 then brings the rest to opacity 0. Also have a transition effect in there. Anyways my question if you look at the JavaScript in my code is:

A: Am I doing that right?
B: Is there a better way without having so much code?

Here's the relevant code:

```
<div id="navwrap">

<a href="#" onclick="toggle()">pic 1</a>
<a href="#" onclick="toggle2()">pic 2</a>
<a href="#" onclick="toggle3()">pic 3</a>
<a href="#" onclick="toggle4()">pic 4</a>

</div>

<img id="pic1" class="pic" src="http://miriadna.com/desctopwalls/images/max/Ideal-landscape.jpg">

<img id="pic2" class="pic" src="http://www.hdwallpaperscool.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/nature-landscape-hd-wallpapers-widescreen-nature-desktop-images.jpg">

<img id="pic3" class="pic" src="http://images.fanpop.com/images/image_uploads/JAPAN-LANDSCAPE-japan-419407_1920_1440.jpg">

<img id="pic4" class="pic" src="http://www.personaltouchcolorado.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/Lawn-Landscape.jpg">

<script>
var w=document.getElementById('pic1'); 
var x=document.getElementById('pic2');
var y=document.getElementById('pic3');
var z=document.getElementById('pic4');
</script>

<script>
function toggle()
{
    if (w.style.opacity=='0')
    {
        w.style.opacity='1';
    }
    else
    {
        w.style.opacity='0';
    }
    if (w.style.opacity=='1')
    {
        w.style.opacity='1';
    }
    else
    {
        w.style.opacity='1';
    }
    {
        x.style.opacity='0';
    }
    {
        y.style.opacity='0';
    }
    {
        z.style.opacity='0';
    }
}
</script>

<script>
function toggle2()
{
    if (x.style.opacity=='1')
    {
        x.style.opacity='0';
    }
    else
    {
        x.style.opacity='1';
    }
    if (x.style.opacity=='1')
    {
        x.style.opacity='1';
    }
    else
    {
        x.style.opacity='1';
    }
    {
        w.style.opacity='0';
    }
    {
        y.style.opacity='0';
    }
    {
        z.style.opacity='0';
    }
}
</script>

<script>
function toggle3()
{
    if (y.style.opacity=='1')
    {
        y.style.opacity='0';
    }
    else
    {
        y.style.opacity='1';
    }
    if (y.style.opacity=='1')
    {
        y.style.opacity='1';
    }
    else
    {
        y.style.opacity='1';
    }
    {
        w.style.opacity='0';
    }
    {
        x.style.opacity='0';
    }
    {
        z.style.opacity='0';
    }
}
</script>

<script>
function toggle4()
{
    if (z.style.opacity=='1')
    {
        z.style.opacity='0';
    }
    else
    {
        z.style.opacity='1';
    }
    if (z.style.opacity=='1')
    {
        z.style.opacity='1';
    }
    else
    {
        z.style.opacity='1';
    }
    {
        w.style.opacity='0';
    }
    {
        x.style.opacity='0';
    }
    {
        y.style.opacity='0';
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Well, if/elses in general are much easier if you indent them properly.

Comment: Try using a switch statement. See [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FStatements%2Fswitch) for more information.

Comment: Sorry this is my second day with javascript, I took a guess at this code and it works and just wanted to see if I'm doing it right.

Comment: OP needs a good tutorial, not help about a specific javascript situation.

Comment: Haha absolutely. I can only read so much without trying it out. Obviously I need to read more

Comment: try yourself then ask here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parametrize the calls:

```
<a href="#" onclick="toggle(1)">pic 1</a>
<a href="#" onclick="toggle(2)">pic 2</a>
<a href="#" onclick="toggle(3)">pic 3</a>
<a href="#" onclick="toggle(4)">pic 4</a>
```

And make a single, much smarter, function:

```
function toggle(id)
{
    var el = document.querySelectorAll('.pic');
    for(var i = 0; i != el.length; i++)
        el[i].style.opacity = 0;
    document.getElementById('pic'+id).style.opacity = 1;
}
```

`document.querySelectorAll` only works in more recent browsers (specifically not in IE8 or below) but that's rather academic - on a production site you'd be using a library like Mootools or jQuery that abstracts that away underneath.

Comment: This seems to easy, I am going to try this later thanks!

Comment: This works great! The only part I can't wrap my head around is the for argument.. 0 is not equal to .pic length increment ? I'll figure it out. Back to the books thanks!

Comment: That's standard `for` syntax in C, C#, C++, Java, PHP, Javascript and just about every other current language, so yeah, look it up in the books  ;)

Comment: I understand the for.. Just don't understand the .pic length part but no worries im reading more anyways thank you

Comment: Also, if the answer solves your problem, accept it by clicking the checkmark to the left of it (underneath the votes).

Answer (score 0):

Your code is indeed very inefficient, but the big problem is that your if/else loops are written wrongly.

First, the {} after the if/else start a 'block', no need for the extra {} you added.

Secondly, you can use a function argument to set the target image, thus making it so you only need a single function to execute your code.

Third, you are currently hard-coding the images, as they all have a class you can use the `document.getElementsByTagName` function and check images that have their `className` property set to `pic` (If you do not care about supporting older browsers such as IE8 and below, you can simply use `document.querySelectorAll`)

Comment: I could just use one set of curlys {} for the code?

Comment: @user2762183 Yes, you just do `if(statement){/*statement true code*/}else{/*statement false code*/}` it could be even shorter, but that requires a high enough understanding of javascript to understand why elseif does not exist in javascript

Answer (score 0):

with further explanation of what Niels said about using jquery, you can do this with the following code.

include jquery in your document

```
function toggle(id){
    $('.pic').css('opacity', '0');
    $('#pic'+id).css('opacity', '1');
}
```

besides note 3 points

1. indent code.
2. use switch statement for such scenario if needed.
3. for such scenario make function which dynamically handle such operation
   where a group of items have to be handle same way.

Comment: I'm trying to learn JavaScript only first. Will be moving on later to JQuery for sure thanks for the tips